# GitHub Probot : Error deploying Probot app on Now

Tags: github, github-api, vercel, probot

I cloned [wip-bot](https://github.com/gr2m/wip-bot) and tried to deploy the bot on Now.
I followed all the instructions given here (All steps): https://probot.github.io/docs/deployment/#now
However, while deploying I faced the following error:

```
aps120797@XENON-PC:/mnt/e/GSoC/wip-bot/wip-bot$ now -e APP_ID=10846 -e WEBHOOK_SECRET=development -e NODE_ENV=production -e PRIVATE_KEY=private-key.pem
> Deploying /mnt/e/GSoC/wip-bot/wip-bot under aps120797
> Error! No secret found by uid or name "wip-bot-log-level"
> More details: https://err.sh/now-cli/env-no-secret
```

Where could I be possibly going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am running and deploying application on Now using now-cli.

The error says that you haven't defined the `LOG_LEVEL` of the App.

To get the verbose logging, add `-e LOG_LEVEL=trace` in the command.
Thus, your command now becomes,

```
now -e APP_ID=10846 -e WEBHOOK_SECRET=development -e NODE_ENV=production -e PRIVATE_KEY=private-key.pem -e LOG_LEVEL=trace
```

Also, if you want to see less details, instead of a verbose logging, you can simple replace trace with info, i.e., add `-e LOG_LEVEL=info`.
Thus, your command becomes,

```
now -e APP_ID=10846 -e WEBHOOK_SECRET=development -e NODE_ENV=production -e PRIVATE_KEY=private-key.pem -e LOG_LEVEL=info
```

With this, your error will be solved and the bot will work fine.
**TIP:** If you face any other similar Error: "No secret found", simply specifying environment variable and secret like this fill fix the problem.

```
now -e VARIABLE_NAME=@secret-name
```